# TYPO3 lib vs temp in FLUIDTEMPLATE

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I read somewhere that if you build for example menu in TYPO3 you should use `temp` instead of `lib` (for performance reason). It is strange, but in all fluid tutorials everyone use `lib` for building menu.

Is it normal or maybe in fluid we should use `lib`?

Comment: I see that you read that : http://blog.sebastiaandejonge.com/articles/2010/september/16/typoscript-temp-vs-lib/
But this one is a good complement for the difference between "reference" and "assign" : http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptSyntaxReference/Syntax/TypoScriptSyntax/Index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`temp` is temporary - it's not cached... you can't even reference it any way...

`lib` opposite is *stable* so it's cached and you can use a references like `lib.foo < lib.bar` in TS

In very general, if your site is cached properly `lib` is more useful than `temp`.